# Arrayformula replacement for sumifs formula with date range and other criteria

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DcA87HF9yf4Ooh4qOzG1q0Hle00b2EH9O5XoMkS51OM/edit?usp=sharing):

Columns `H` and `I` give the sum of `Dr` or `Cr` for each `Account` within a date range.

I am looking for an arrayformula which replaces these so that if a new `Account` is added in column G (e.g."Account 4") then the arrayformula would calculate the totals for this new Account, instead of having to copy the existing `=sumifs` formula down.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
    =MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(G3:G),2,LAMBDA(r,c,LAMBDA(sums,
IF(AND(sums>0,c=1),sums,IF(AND(sums<0,c=2),-sums,"")))
(SUMIFS($C$3:$C,$D$3:$D,INDEX(G3:G,r),$A$3:$A,">="&$H$1,$A$3:$A,"<="&$I$1)-SUMIFS($C$3:$C,$E$3:$E,INDEX(G3:G,r),$A$3:$A,">="&$H$1,$A$3:$A,"<="&$I$1))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED FORMULA**:

`=MAP(BYROW(G3:G,LAMBDA(gx,IF(gx="",,SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,A:A>=H1,A:A<=I1,D:D=gx)))))),BYROW(G3:G,LAMBDA(gx,IF(gx="",,SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,A:A>=H1,A:A<=I1,E:E=gx)))))),LAMBDA(ax,bx,IF(ax="",,IF(ax-bx>0,{ax-bx,IFERROR(1/0)},{IFERROR(1/0),-(ax-bx)}))))`

-

[image]

Comment: Nice formula, but it will throw an error if an account doesn't appear both in Cr and Dr every month

Comment: oopsie.. thanks martin:) will recheck

Answer (score 1):

delete all your formulae in `H3:I` range and use this in `H3`:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(d, c, {IF(d>c, d-c, ), IF(c>d, c-d, )})
 (QUERY({A3:D},       "select sum(Col3) 
 where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(H1, "e-m-d")&"' 
   and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(I1, "e-m-d")&"' group by Col4 label sum(Col3)''"), 
 QUERY({A3:C, E3:E}, "select sum(Col3) 
 where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(H1, "e-m-d")&"' 
   and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(I1, "e-m-d")&"' group by Col4 label sum(Col3)''")))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, {INDEX(x,,1), {D2:E2; QUERY({
 IF(INDEX(x,,2)<INDEX(x,,3), INDEX(x,,3)-INDEX(x,,2), ), 
 IF(INDEX(x,,3)<INDEX(x,,2), INDEX(x,,2)-INDEX(x,,3), )}, "offset 1", )}})
 (QUERY({A3:D, IFERROR(D3:D/0, D2); A3:C, E3:E, IFERROR(E3:E/0, E2)},
 "select Col4,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(H1, "e-m-d")&"' 
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(I1, "e-m-d")&"' 
  group by Col4 
  pivot Col5")))
```

[image]

Comment: Always interesting your views! But it will be dependant on having values in both Cr and Dr, that every account appears each month and the order is alphabetical in G. Am I right?

Comment: @Martín yes and yes. updated with bulletproof solution

Comment: Nice approach 